# maximum recursion depth exceeded for finding ace of spades

Tags: python

The problem is given a deck of 52 cards, find the Ace of Spades. A computer randomly selects a card. The same card can be picked repeatedly.

Best case scenario on this search is 1, worst case scenario is infinity.
What's the average number of cards you'd have to see to find the Ace of Spades?

The result should be 52. My codes to the problem are below, but got the error message when soving it with recursion. 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'. Can you advise?

```
# solve by recursion

def to_infinity():
    index=0
    while 1:
        yield index
        index += 1

result = 0 
for n in to_infinity():
    """
    calculate the expected average number of cards 
    """
    def prob(n):
        """
        :param n: the nth card being draw
        :return: the probability that the nth card is ace of spades
        """
        if n == 1:
            return 1.0 / 52
        else:
            p = 1 - (1.0 / 52)
            return prob(n-1) * p

    average = prob(n) * n
    result += average
    if n > 10000: break
    print(result)


# not solve by recursion

def to_infinity():
    index=0
    while 1:
        yield index
        index += 1

result = 0 
for n in to_infinity():
    """
    calculate the expected average number of cards 
    """

    p = ((1 - (1.0 / 52)) ** (n - 1)) * (1.0 / 52)
    average = p * n
    result += average
    if n > 10000: break
    print(result)
```

Comment: Your recursion doesn't terminate when the input `n = 0`, because `n-1` will never reach the base case `n == 1`. That's the first value of `n` that you try.

Comment: Side (style) note: `while 1` should be `while True`, and `to_infinity` should be `itertools.count`.

Comment: FWIW, `itertools.count()` does what your `infinity()` does.

Comment: Why are you using recursion in the first place? Is this purely for learning purposes? Why are you defining a function inside a loop?

Comment: yes it was for learning purpose, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

revised codes. Adjusted the recursion limit and the boundary condition. It works now.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) 
import itertools
import time
start_time = time.time()

result = 0
for n in itertools.count():
    """
    calculate the expected average number of cards 
    """
    def prob(n):
        """

        :param n: the nth card being draw
        :return: the probability that the nth card is ace of spades
        """
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n == 1:
            return 1.0 / 52
        else:
            p = 1 - (1.0 / 52)
            return prob(n-1) * p

    average = prob(n) * n
    result += average
    if n > 9000: break
    print(result)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```